# Transfer for the group of coinvariants: a reference request

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group and $M$ be a $G$-module,
that is, an abelian group written additively on which $G$ acts:
$$ (g,m)\mapsto g m.$$
We consider the *group of coinvariants*
$$ M_G:=G/\langle g m -m\ |\ g\in G,\,m\in M\rangle. $$
Let $H\subseteq G$ be a subgroup of finite index.
I am trying to understand the *transfer map*
$ M_G\to M_H$.

Choose a section $s\colon H\setminus G\to G$ of the projection $G\to H\setminus G$ onto the quotient space $H\setminus G$.
Consider the homomorphism
$$ N\colon M\to M,\quad\ m\mapsto \sum_{x\in H\setminus G} s(x) m.$$
This homomorphism  $N$ induces  a homomorphism
$$
N_*\colon M\to M_H,
$$
which is clearly independent of the choice of the section $s$.

> **Question 1.**
> Why does the homomorphism $N_*$ descend to a homomorphism
> $$ N_{**}\colon M_G\to M_H\ ?$$

In other words, for $m\in M$ and $g\in G$, why is
$$ \sum_{x\in H\setminus G} s(x)\cdot( g m -m)$$
a linear combination of elements of the form $h m'-m'$ for $h\in H$ and $m'\in M$?

I have asked Question 1 in Mathematics Stack Exchange https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4833018/37763
and got an excellent answer by darij grinberg.
Now, in my paper I can refer to this answer.
However, if possible, I would like to refer to a book or a paper.

> **Question 2.** What are possible  references to an answer to Question 1 (in addition to the answer in MSE)?

Comment: 6.7.16 of Weibel's homological algebra book states this, but only when $H$ is normal.

Comment: On page 81 under (B) in Brown's group cohomology book he defines the transfer map with a parenthetical remark on why it is well defined.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Thank you. However, the parenthetical remark is not that helpful...

Comment: Lemma 9.91 in Roman's homological algebra book gives a detailed proof

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Thank you! Yes, Lemma 9.91 in Rotman's An Introduction to Homologicla Algebra is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take some care about left vs. right modules, and then use associativity and functoriality of the tensor products for the associative $\mathbb{Z}$-algebras $\mathbb{Z}G$ and $\mathbb{Z}H$.

Write $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ for the integers with a trivial right group action. The coinvariants of the left module $M$ can be thought of as
$$
M_G = \underline{\mathbb{Z}} \otimes_G M.
$$
Restriction to the action of $H$ can similarly be written as a tensor product with the bimodule ${}_H G_G$, so we also get a formula for $M_H$:
$$
M_H = \underline{\mathbb{Z}} \otimes_H G \otimes_G M.
$$
The transfer map $M_G \to M_H$ is functorial in $M$, suggesting that the map acts only on the tensor factor preceding the $M$. And indeed, we induce the transfer using a map of right $G$-modules

$$
\underline{\mathbb{Z}} \to \underline{\mathbb{Z}} \otimes_H G = G_H.
$$
The coinvariants of $H$ acting on the left of $G$ are cosets. As there is a single orbit, any $G$-equivariant map from $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is a multiple of the map sending $1$ to the sum of the cosets.